# Deploy laravel on blueMix

Tags: php, laravel, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-tools

I have a VPS of blueMix, My cPanel's file Manager have folder `public_html` where i dropped a file `index.php` having some php `echo 'tesing';` which wasn't loading up, After some research i found out that my `root Directory` is `/var/www/html`. But any how i dropped my project there like `/var/www/html/project` and then came up checked like `example.com` and that redirected me to the hosting default page, `example.com/project` show project root files and folders, `example.com/project/public` returned internal server error 500. Permissions seems ok.

What am i missing, Is there a slandered way ? Please help out.

**Q1** : How can i set my root directory `public_html`.

**Q2** : How to deploy laravel in `/var/www/html` or `public_html`.

Comment: No i haven't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research, I easiest way is to have a server with out a lamp stack, Install a custom lamp stack, One by one component, Look for the apache configuration, Set the permissions, And you are good to go.

Comment: hey bro, kindly help me in accomplishing this app that I want 2 deploy I found this tutorial but the second link inside 
> Deploying to bluemix section is broken.... 
tihs specifc url :  https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/getting-started-laravel-bluemix

Answer (score 0):

**modify this Lines from Public->index.php**   to the public_html .

```
   require __DIR__.'/../public_html/bootstrap/autoload.php';
   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../public_html/bootstrap/app.php';
```

and check..